# Number of executions of the same sub query by the DB engine

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have this SQL query

```
SELECT
  (select count(*) from  tableA) as cnt,
  t1.*

FROM
    (
     SELECT t.*
     FROM
         (
          SELECT * FROM tableA
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT * FROM tableB
         ) t
     ORDER BY [col1]
     OFFSET 1000 ROWS  --    
     FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
    ) t1
```

This query works. The question is - how many times his subquery executes, 1 or 50?
`(select count(*) from  tableA) as cnt`

Basically, I know that if you have multiple `GETDATE()` in your query, it executes only once and value is reused. I am wondering if the analyzer is smart enough to know that it already executed this subquery, which has no correlation to other records.

Here is the  [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyw4IvfXt)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution plan shows 4 scans of the primary key of `[some_schema].[table_a]`, which indicates that SQL Server is indeed reading the table once per reference in the source query.

This part of the plan shows the `UNION` of the two tables referenced in the `FROM` clause:

[image]

The two subqueries that appear as part of the `SELECT` clause are shown in the execution plan here:

[image]

I created a simple [repro](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/mcve) that shows how `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` can also show you that the table is being scanned 4 times:

```
USE tempdb;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[table_a];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_a]
(
    c1      int             NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , c2    sysname         NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_a] (c1, c2)
SELECT TOP(1000) 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    , sc1.name
FROM sys.syscolumns sc1;

SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT
  (select count(*) from [dbo].[table_a] as cnt),
  (select count(*) from [dbo].[table_a] as cnt),
  t1.*

FROM
    (
     SELECT t.*
     FROM
         (
          SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table_a]
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table_a]
         ) t
     ORDER BY [c1]
     OFFSET 1000 ROWS 
     FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
    ) t1
```

The "Messages" output shows the following:

> Table 'table_a'. Scan count 4, logical reads 24, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

As you can see, it clearly states the scan count is 4.

Comment: Ok, great. So, it means SQL server does not internally cache the aggregate value. Cool

Comment: I realize you probably dumbed it down to post here, but it's a bit of a strange query as written.  If you are having a specific issue optimizing a query like this, I would post a new question with the exact query you're actually running (include a link to this one if it helps).  It's quite possible there are a number of optimizations that could make the result much quicker.

Comment: You're right, it is simplified. This is a general question. Just to see, in which direction to go. The query does not exist yet, it will be dynamically generated based on number of unions, etc. I was trying to see if DB Engine caches the single-value result per query. Depends on that, I could change the location of placement. I am more app coder than DB dev. Query optimizers improve all the time, what correct yesterday may not be today.. Thank you